# loading local data in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to load local data in jqgrid , but its not getting loaded.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/mee0r0vt/)

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["OrderID", "CustomerID"],
                   colModel: [
                    { label: 'Order ID', name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75 },
                    { label: 'Customer  ID', name: 'CustomerID', width: 150 },

                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                height: 250,
                pager: "#pager",
                data:jsData      
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point the `data` to `jsData.rows` rather than `jsData`. The root of the object doesn't directly contain the array or keys that you're trying to display.

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/6bx4w3m6/

Comment: +1, Yes, correctly! Alternatively one can use `datatype: "jsonstring", datastr: myData`: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/mee0r0vt/2/